# Query for one dataframe row based on row in another dataframe & compare values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, if-statement

So I have two data frames. The first data frame contains numerical data that is used to "score" the second data frame which contains simulation data.

df1 = base records

df2 = simulation records

**Part 1:** What I am trying to accomplish is to query df1 'base records' to find the row that has the most recent timestamp to that in the df2 'simulation records' where the **"Name" & "Time" columns match exactly.**

**Part 2:** Then I want to use an if then function to determine whether a value in the simulation record row fall between a range created using two values from the base record row and return a boolean.

low range = df1['Po']-df1['Ref']

high range = df1['Po']+df1['Ref']

*if df2['Sim'] falls in between the low range & high range of its most recent df1 base record then I want to return true in the new column "Sim Score"
otherwise return false*

**Part 3:** I want to repeat Part 1 & Part 2 for each row in the simulation records.

**helpful information:**

- df1 (base records) have more or less rows than df2 (simulation records)
- df1 has more columns than df2
- some columns in df1 have the same name but different values in df2
- ideally want to be able to slice both dataframes where the if then function only sees the two rows used in the comparison
- **only need the most recent df1 base record** to compare to the df2 simulation record
- previously accomplished this in google sheets with if then & query combination formula dragged down entire sheet (want to replace with python & pandas)

```
df1 base records example (columns that matter)

Timestamp            Name     Time     Po  Ref

7/11/2022 11:30:00   trial   20 mins   5   2

7/10/2022 04:00:00   trial   20 mins   4   4

7/09/2022 02:45:00   trial   20 mins   2   2

6/28/2022 03:45:00   trial   20 mins   3   6
```

```
df2 simulation records example (columns that matter)

Timestamp             Name     Time     Sim

7/10/2022 05:15:00    trial   20 mins   7

7/11/2022 12:45:00    trial   20 mins   4

7/12/2022 03:30:00    trial   20 mins   8
```

```
desired result of new column added to df2

Timestamp             Name     Time     Sim  Sim Score

7/10/2022 05:15:00    trial   20 mins   7    True

7/11/2022 12:45:00    trial   20 mins   4    True

7/12/2022 03:30:00    trial   20 mins   8    False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.reindex`, its `method` offer **nearest** to find the computable index(e.g., string can not calculate distance)

Or use `merge_asof`, its `direction` offer **nearest**.

---

### Method 1:

`reindex()` with `method='nearest'`

```
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df1.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
df1['l_r'] = df1['Po'] - df1['Ref']
df1['h_r'] = df1['Po'] + df1['Ref']
print(df1)
###
                      Name     Time  Po  Ref  l_r  h_r
Timestamp                                             
2022-07-11 11:30:00  trial  20 mins   5    2    3    7
2022-07-10 04:00:00  trial  20 mins   4    4    0    8
2022-07-09 02:45:00  trial  20 mins   2    2    0    4
2022-06-28 03:45:00  trial  20 mins   3    6   -3    9
```

```
df2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'])
df2.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
print(df2)
###
                      Name     Time  Sim
Timestamp                               
2022-07-10 05:15:00  trial  20 mins    7
2022-07-11 12:45:00  trial  20 mins    4
2022-07-12 03:30:00  trial  20 mins    8
```

```
temp = df2.join(df1.reindex(df2.index, method='nearest'), lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
print(temp)
```

[image]

As you can see, this is `df2.join(df1)`,

> join multiple DataFrame objects by index at once.

with `method='nearest'`, in this case, it would join `df2` and `df1` by the nearest `Timestamp` index.

```
df2['Sim Score'] = temp['Sim'].between(temp['l_r'], temp['h_r']).values
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df2)
###
            Timestamp   Name     Time  Sim  Sim Score
0 2022-07-10 05:15:00  trial  20 mins    7       True
1 2022-07-11 12:45:00  trial  20 mins    4       True
2 2022-07-12 03:30:00  trial  20 mins    8      False
```

---

### Method 2:

`merge_asof()` with `direction='nearest'`
this way is not executed with indexed value, therefore we don't have to set column `Timestamp` as index. But it needs binding objects(in this case we merge on column `Timestamp`)sorted.

```
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
# df1.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
df1['l_r'] = df1['Po'] - df1['Ref']
df1['h_r'] = df1['Po'] + df1['Ref']
df1.sort_values(by='Timestamp', inplace=True)
print(df1)
###
            Timestamp   Name     Time  Po  Ref  l_r  h_r
3 2022-06-28 03:45:00  trial  20 mins   3    6   -3    9
2 2022-07-09 02:45:00  trial  20 mins   2    2    0    4
1 2022-07-10 04:00:00  trial  20 mins   4    4    0    8
0 2022-07-11 11:30:00  trial  20 mins   5    2    3    7
```

```
df2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Timestamp'])
# df2.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
df2.sort_values(by='Timestamp', inplace=True)
print(df2)
###
            Timestamp   Name     Time  Sim
0 2022-07-10 05:15:00  trial  20 mins    7
1 2022-07-11 12:45:00  trial  20 mins    4
2 2022-07-12 03:30:00  trial  20 mins    8
```

```
temp = pd.merge_asof(df2 ,df1[['Timestamp', 'l_r', 'h_r']], on='Timestamp', direction='nearest')
print(temp)
```

[image]
As you can see, this is `pd.merge_asof(df2, df1)`,

> This is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys. Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.

For each row in the left DataFrame:

> A “nearest” search selects the row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is closest in absolute distance to the left’s key.

```
df2['Sim Score'] = temp['Sim'].between(temp['l_r'], temp['h_r']).values
print(df2)
###
            Timestamp   Name     Time  Sim  Sim Score
0 2022-07-10 05:15:00  trial  20 mins    7       True
1 2022-07-11 12:45:00  trial  20 mins    4       True
2 2022-07-12 03:30:00  trial  20 mins    8      False
```

Frankly speaking, working on indexed things would be faster if you have a large dataset.

#### Method 2 (on multiple keys)

I remodified `df1` adding different Name and Time

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp':['7/11/2022 11:30:00','7/11/2022 11:30:00','7/10/2022 04:00:00','7/10/2022 04:00:00','7/09/2022 02:45:00','6/28/2022 03:45:00'],
                    'Name':['trial','trial','trial','non-trial','trial','trial'],
                    'Time':['20 mins','30 mins','20 mins','20 mins','20 mins','20 mins'],
                    'Po':[5, 6, 4, 1, 2, 3],
                    'Ref':[2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6]})
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df1['l_r'] = df1['Po'] - df1['Ref']
df1['h_r'] = df1['Po'] + df1['Ref']
df1.sort_values(by='Timestamp', inplace=True)
print(df1)
###
            Timestamp       Name     Time  Po  Ref  l_r  h_r
5 2022-06-28 03:45:00      trial  20 mins   3    6   -3    9
4 2022-07-09 02:45:00      trial  20 mins   2    2    0    4
2 2022-07-10 04:00:00      trial  20 mins   4    4    0    8
3 2022-07-10 04:00:00  non-trial  20 mins   1    3   -2    4
0 2022-07-11 11:30:00      trial  20 mins   5    2    3    7
1 2022-07-11 11:30:00      trial  30 mins   6    2    4    8
```

```
print(df2)
###
            Timestamp   Name     Time  Sim
0 2022-07-10 05:15:00  trial  20 mins    7
1 2022-07-11 12:45:00  trial  20 mins    4
2 2022-07-12 03:30:00  trial  20 mins    8
```

#### Important:

can only merge_asof on a single key, therefore others would utilize `by=` to deal with.

```
temp = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1[['Timestamp', 'Name', 'Time', 'l_r', 'h_r']], on='Timestamp', by=['Name','Time'], direction='nearest')
print(temp)
```

[image]

```
df2['Sim Score'] = temp['Sim'].between(temp['l_r'], temp['h_r']).values
print(df2)
###
            Timestamp   Name     Time  Sim  Sim Score
0 2022-07-10 05:15:00  trial  20 mins    7       True
1 2022-07-11 12:45:00  trial  20 mins    4       True
2 2022-07-12 03:30:00  trial  20 mins    8      False
```

---

Reference:
[pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)
[pandas.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)
[merging/join concept](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-the-pandas-merge-you-should-know-for-combining-datasets-526b9ecaf184)

Comment: could you edit your two methods to show how in the base records the "Name" and "Time" fields are matched to the simulation record?

ie. Trial & 20 mins is compared to Trial & 20 mins

Comment: I've updated the post for further explanation on `temp` with **method1** and **method2** respectively.

Comment: If you need to merge on multiple fields(`'Timestamp'`, `'Name'`, `'Time'`) I added **Method 2 (on multiple keys)** on the following part.

Comment: If you are curious about how `join`/`merge` work, please refer to the reference beneath the post.

Comment: Thank you! Your Method 2 on multiple keys worked perfectly for my datasets and project. I greatly appreciate you sharing this information with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't provide code to construct the dataframe, I will sketch a potential solution:

First, I will assume that you have only one timestamp per day (which it looks like in your examples). Accordingly, I would truncate or split the timestamp to only have the date in one column. This is done so we can join the dataframes based on the date, i.e. use `set_index("date_column")` for both dataframes (use an inner-join to only keep the rows where the date was present in both dataframes). Finally, you can use `apply()` to check your condition:

```
df_joined['Sim Score'] = df_joined.apply(lambda row: (row['Po']-row['Ref'] <= row['Sim']) and (row['Po']+row['Ref'] >= row['Sim']), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `pandasql`:
But note that you better add a unique constraint to one of the columns (e.g. a number of trial)

```
from pandasql import sqldf

df3 = sqldf('''
    SELECT df2.Timestamp AS Date, df1.Name, df1.Time, df2.Sim,
    
    CASE
        WHEN Sim >= (df1.Po - df1.Ref) AND Sim <= (df1.Po + df1.Ref) THEN 'True'
        WHEN Sim < (df1.Po - df1.Ref) OR Sim > (df1.Po + df1.Ref) THEN 'False'
    END AS 'Sim Score'
    
    FROM df1, df2
    
    WHERE df2.Name == df1.Name AND df2.Time == df1.Time
    ORDER BY Date ASC
''')
```

---

Also to work with `datetime` format in `sqldf` you need to name your Timestamp column as ***date*** in the query. If you need to get only let's say first/earliest 5 results add `LIMIT 5` in the end of the query.

If you need to get closest date in df2 to df1 try this:

```
from pandasql import sqldf

df3 = sqldf('''
    SELECT df2.Timestamp AS Date1, df2.Timestamp AS Date2, 
           df1.Name, df1.Time, df2.Sim,
    
    CASE
        WHEN Sim >= (df1.Po - df1.Ref) AND Sim <= (df1.Po + df1.Ref) THEN 'True'
        WHEN Sim < (df1.Po - df1.Ref) OR Sim > (df1.Po + df1.Ref) THEN 'False'
    END AS 'Sim Score'
    
    FROM df1, df2
    
    WHERE df2.Name == df1.Name AND df2.Time == df1.Time
    and Date1 <= Date2
    group by Date2
    ORDER BY Date1 ASC
''')
```

Comment: while I love your query based approach we are missing a key part in the above answer. I need the record pulled from df1 (base records) to be the most recent timestamp to that shown in df2(simulation records) while also matching the "Name" and "Time" shown above.

Comment: My bad, missed it. So if we get Name and Time from df1 and Timestamp from df2 and sort Timestamp in ascending order -- would it be the desired output?
-- also fixed the answer above in this way. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: Also added second option for closest next date to df2 in df1